# Distinc values of items coming from two querysets in Django view/template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I need to output a list of works performed by a performer. The same work can have been performed multiple times, and in two different kind of event (e.g. `performanceOfWork` and `Event` models).

```
class Work(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) # max_length = required

class performanceOfWork(models.Model):

    solo_performer = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
    performed = models.ForeignKey('Work', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Event(models.Model):

    solo_performer = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
    repertoire = models.ManyToManyField(Work, blank=True)
```

In the view I managed to get the distinct values from each of the two models:

```
context['repertoire_from_works'] = performanceOfWork.objects.filter(solo_performer=self.get_object().id).values('performed__title').distinct()
context['repertoire_from_events'] = Event.objects.filter(solo_performer=self.get_object().id).values('repertoire__title').distinct()
```

But then, how do I deal with the same work being performed in both models? I just want to output it once. This is a very wonky attempt (which doesn't work because it checks both values within one nested loop):

```
      <ul>{% for work_works in repertoire_from_works.all %}
        {% for work_events in repertoire_from_events.all %}
          {% if work_works.performed__title == work_events.repertoire__title%}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            <li>{{ work_works.performed__title }}</li>
            {% endif %}

          {% else %}
          <li>{{ work_events.repertoire__title }}</li>
          <li>{{ work_works.performed__title }}</li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can query on the `Work` model:

```
from django.db.models import Q

object = self.get_object()
context['works'] = Work.objects.filter(
    Q(performanceofwork__solo_performer=object.id) |
    Q(event__solo_performer=object.id)
).distinct()
```

This will give you a collection of distinct `Work` objects, this is often better, since a Django model is "richer" than a set of scalar values. If two works have the same title, then the different works will be returned.

If you really only need the titles, then you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

object = self.get_object()
context['works'] = Work.objects.filter(
    Q(performanceofwork__solo_performer=object.id) |
    Q(event__solo_performer=object.id)
).values_list('title', flat=True).distinct()
```

Then you get an iterable of strings (the titles).

Comment: You nailed it once again! Great stuff, Willem. And adding a `.order_by('title')` at the end of my queryset orders it by title. Thanks.